# Yii2 Getting a certain value in a textinput-field

Tags: forms, yii2, textinput

I've got a Profile model and a form in which i want to place a (hidden) textinput-field with a representing value from the user.

I managed to get the right (single) value in following dropdown:

```
$form->field($profesta, 'current_establishment')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Profile::find()->where(['id_user' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->all(),'current_establishment','id_user'));
```

But i want to change it to a textinput-field and i think it must be something like:

```
$form->field($model, 'id_user')->hiddenInput(['value' => ???])->label(false);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pleas visit this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153443/yii2-hidden-input-value

Comment: Thank you, i managed to get the right code with this link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [yii2 hidden input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153443/yii2-hidden-input-value)